# How to print a DOUBLE with a variable INT

Tags: java, casting, formatting, int, double

I'm doing my school homework and I got stuck. I set my variable as INT and now I can't change it because I'm using it for other calculations. Is there a way which I can print 3 numbers after the dot? I tried with `printf` and `(double)` but it didn't work.

This is my piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // Printing Inverse
{
    System.out.print("[");
    output.print("[");
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        sol[i][j] = adj[i][j] / det;
        System.out.printf((double) sol[i][j] + " ");
        output.print((double)sol[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: int is int! int doesn't have _numbers after dot_

Comment: please place the question and the entire code

Comment: @B001ᛦ - It is the simplest way to be sure that we have all of the necessary details.  For example, we need to see the types of `sol`, `adj` and `det`.

Comment: @B001ᛦ as answered by StephenC

Comment: If you want to print an int with its fractional part to 3dp, you can just do this `System.out.println(myInt + ".000")` ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way which I can print 3 numbers after the dot? I tried with printf and (double) but it didn't work.

Well casting the `int` to `double` is not enough to get the expected output.

To print the casted `double` with three decimals, you need to use `%3f` as first parameter in the `printf` method, like this:

```
System.out.printf("%.3f", (double) sol[i][j]);
```

This is a **[live working demo](https://ideone.com/YBK3OK)**.

**Note:**

Note that the result of the division in `sol[i][j] = adj[i][j] / det;` will be a `double`, so you need to declare your variables as `double` instead of `int` to avoid getting Exceptions.

Comment: `%.3f` will print three decimal places. I don't see the period in the code of your answer - between the "%" and the "3"

Comment: @Abra It was just a typo, if you see the demo it was there. :)

Answer (score 2):

By doing the calculation as a int, you are basically "throwing away" information. This means that from that point, it is not possible to get it back.

Since your current code looks like `intVariable = intVariable / intVariable; print((double)intVariable)`, the compiler automatically uses integer division, what basically discards all decimals

You want your code to look like `doubleVariable = intVariable / doubleVariable;print(doubleVariable)`, which would mean casting the divider in the division to a double, and changing the type of `sol` so it could hold `doubles` instead of the type you have now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `sol` is a two-dimensional array of `int`, hence - as @B001 mentioned in his comment - it has no numbers after the decimal point. If all you want to do is print the result of the division: `adj[i][j] / det` as a `double`, I suggest using another variable just for printing the result, i.e.

```
double result = (double) adj[i][j] / det;
sol[i][j] = (int) result;
System.out.printf("%.3f", result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should redefine this variable again, that will not be catastrofic, just be carefull. Eclipse/NetBean will be notifying you if your variable has totally changed or not.

I am not sure, but I think that somewhere in Eclipse you could find a button that changes your variable and all its references.